# using string methods on variant vbscript

Tags: string, vbscript, variant

I am currently having a variant variable with string vartype. That specific variable may contain string such as "005" and I would like to change it to "5" (without converting it to a number),
if it was a regular string I would have done it like so:

Do While Mid(x,1,1)=0
 x = Right(x,Len(x)-1)
Loop

But alas, I cannot do it with a variant.
Is there a way to use the string functions on the variant \ convert the variant to regular string?
if not, is there a different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast it to a number and then back to a string again.

```
strNumber = "005"

If IsNumeric(strNumber) Then
    strNumber = CStr(CLng(strNumber))
End If
```

The `FormatNumber()` function also formats a number as a string:

```
strNumber = "005"

' Reformat the number...
strNumber = FormatNumber(strNumber, 0)
```

Comment: I do not with to convert the string to a number do to the fact the string can represent a number much greater then 
 2147483647.

Comment: Then use `CDbl` instead of `CLng`. The `FormatNumber` function would still work fine with large numbers, too. How big are these numbers? I just tried `FormatNumber` with a 325-digit number and it worked fine.

Comment: CDbl did the trick, it wont be over 10^28 so its enough,
 Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked. Your way would have worked, too, but it's just easier to use the "built-in" methods.